# Undefined _FILES php and getimagesize File cannot be empty

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I have been working on a website and I want to upload an image. I have the following table in MySQL:

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT

  name varchar (30) not null

  image LONGBLOB

```
<?php


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
                    {
                        echo "Please select and image";
                    }
                    else {
                        $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        $image = base64_encode($image);
                        saveimage($name,$image);
                    }
                }
            function saveimage($name , $image)
            {
                $query = "insert into image (name,image)
                    values ('$name', '$image')";
                $result = mysqli_query($query,$conn);
                if($result)
                {
                    echo "<p>Image Uploaded</p>";

                }
                else {
                    echo "<p>Image not Uploaded</p> " . mysql_error();
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I try to upload the image I get the following:

> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: _FILES -- at line 28
>   E_WARNING : type 2 -- getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty -- at line 28
>   Please select and image

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and also in the php.ini I set the post_max_size = 20M

Any ideas?

Comment: too many syntax errors

Comment: Try var_dump($_FILES) at the top of the script so you can see if it is set at all or if the contents are different from what you are expecting.

Comment: `mysqli_query` and `mysql_error()` are for different drivers. Your SQL is open to SQL injections.